# Android support for Torch Mode

Tags: java, android

I've tried looking around for a particular answer to this question but can't find it. Hopefully someone here can help!

I'm trying to get Torch mode to work on all phones (The main problems seem to be Droid X, LG Ally etc.) but can't get it to work for everyone.

I set the Torch mode like this:

```
mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
mParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
```

This seems to work for most phones but not some. I've since implemented a check like this:

```
if(mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode() != null){ ... Set Torch ... }
else { Toast: "Unsupported Phone"; }
```

(That's the short hand version)...

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

It isn't necessarily safe to leave the flash continuously on if the hardware isn't designed to dissipate that kind of thermal influx.  Don't look for a way to circumvent the built-in protection on such phones.

In addition to heat concerns, some flashbulb circuits pre-charge a capacitor and then discharge it quickly through the light.  There isn't any capability for continuously supplying a current large enough to drive the light.

In either case, you're dealing with a hardware restriction and you can't overcome it in software.

Comment: It's never continuously on, rather only for a short time which is up to the user. I'm just trying to find a method that will allow me to set it on for all phones. Please let me know if you have come across a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @John: On some phones, it isn't safe to turn on the flashbulb (flashLED?) for longer than just the brief flash associated with picture taking.  Leaving it on longer than that (or turning it on again too soon before it has a chance to cool) can overheat the circuit and cause damage.  And you shouldn't expect your user to know how long is safe.

Comment: True, I hadn't taken that into consideration. Thanks